# Ember 3.6 super-rentals tutorial LEAFLET_MAPS_API_KEY using environment.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, configuration, environment-variables

While going through the ember 3.6 super-rentals tutorial I ran into a few snags adding the ember-simple-leaflet-maps. 
I couldn't get the environment variable LEAFLET_MAPS_API_KEY to set.
https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/service/

To my understanding, the tutorial has you set an environment variable on your operating system? Maybe I'm wrong in thinking that, but I wanted a way to just add the variable to my project /config/environment.js

Comment: You shouldn't need to do `ember build` and `ember serve`. You should just be able to do `ember serve`. That being said, I'm a little clear what your problem is. From your description, it sounds like you figured out whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: Yep I figured it out. I wanted to share my solution.

Comment: If this is self answering you should add an answer, not put the answer in your question, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I've added your answer as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from OP:

After the addon was installed:

```
ember install ember-simple-leaflet-maps
```

I opened the geocode.js file to see how the service was injecting the api key. Path is:
node_modules\ember-simple-leaflet-maps\addon\services\geocode.js

The line of code was:

```
let accessToken = getOwner(this).resolveRegistration('config:environment')['ember-simple-leaflet-maps'].apiKey;
```

From there I just added the lookup it was looking for to my file /config/environment.js

```
let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'super-rentals',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    'ember-simple-leaflet-maps': {
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };
```

Rebuild the project and serve, my maps are now showing up

```
ember build
ember serve
```